# how do i make each query collapse php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have this PHP and jQuery code which works in coalition with my database. This is the only page. The code runs and gives me a row of data, but when I click the collapse button it only works for the first row. Even if I click any other row, that action affects only the first row and all the other rows collapse, which is useless.

How do I make it so that all rows work? It's like the button is doubled and only works for the first row.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('div#dl_box').on('show', function(e) {
      console.log('show', $(e.target).attr('class'), $(e.target).attr('id'));
      $(e.target).prev('.accordion-heading').addClass('active');
    });

    $('div#dl_box').on('hidden', function(e) {
      console.log('hidden', $(e.target).attr('class'), $(e.target).attr('id'));
      $(e.target).prev('.accordion-heading').removeClass('active');
    });

  });
  $(document).ready(function() {});

</script>

<?php
 $connection = ($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect('localhost',  'root',  ''));
    ((bool)mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "USE " . 'db'));

    $query = "SELECT * FROM AS_Questions"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $query);
    if (!$result) {
       printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }

    echo "<table>"; 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
    echo "
    <section class='section swatch-white editable-swatch'>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='panel panel-primary panel-ws-download'>
                <div class='panel-heading'>
                    <a href='#group_accordion_stable' class='accordion-toggle collapsed' data-parent='#accordion_download' data-toggle='collapse'>
                    " . $row['Question'] . "
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id='group_accordion_stable' class='panel-collapse collapse' style='height: 0px;'>
                    <div class='panel-body'>
                        <!-- first -->
                        <ul class='list-unstyled list-ws-download'>
                            <li>" . $row['Answer'] . "</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    ";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
    }

    echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

    ((is_null($___mysqli_res = mysqli_close($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]))) ? false : $___mysqli_res); //Make sure to close out the database connection
    ?>
```

Comment: Is this the full code on your page? Because in your `js` part you targeting elements with id `dl_box` and with class `accordion-heading`, but I can't find them in your `html` part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample for u.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.default {
    display: block;
    background: pink;
    height: 3em;
    width: 10em;
    transition: height 5s, background 3s;   /*collaspe speed*/  
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.expanded {
    height: 10em;
    background: yellow;
    transition: height 1s, background 2s;   /*expand speed*/
    /*display: none;*/
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($i <5) {
    $i++;
    echo '<div class="default"  id="ChangeThisId_'.$i.'">';
        echo '
            <a href="#" 
            name="ChangeThisId_'.$i.'"      
            onclick="changeHeight(this.name)">
            Click me '. $i .'
            </a>
            ';
    echo '</div>';  
}
// above return in html.
// <div class="default" id="ChangeThisId_1">
// <a href="#" name="ChangeThisId_1">CLick me 1</a>
// </div>
// <div class="default" id="ChangeThisId_2">
// <a href="#" name="ChangeThisId_2">Click me 2</a>
// and so on till ...5
?>
</body>
<script>
function changeHeight(x){
    //alert(x); //x return name of clicked <a> tag.
    document.getElementById(x).classList.toggle("expanded");     
}
</script>
</html>
```

This is using css, html(+php to create row), and native javascript.
The idea is to assign an unique for each row.
others are quite self explanatory, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

to anyone coming in here in search of sql data display with accordian collapse. here Qid is my tables auto incremented value. AS_Questions is my table name. db is my database name.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>



<?php
$connection = ($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect('localhost',  'root',  'password')); //The Blank string is the password
((bool)mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "USE " . 'db'));

$query = "SELECT * FROM AS_Questions"; 
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $query);
if (!$result) {
   printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

echo "<table>"; 


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo "


<div class='panel-group' id='accordion'> <!-- accordion 1 -->
   <div class='panel panel-primary'>

        <div class='panel-heading'> <!-- panel-heading -->
            <h4 class='panel-title'> <!-- title 1 -->
            <a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#accordion" . $row['Qid'] . "'>
              " . $row['Question'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='fa fa-eye' style='float: right;'></i>
            </a>
           </h4>
        </div>
        <!-- panel body -->
        <div id='accordion" . $row['Qid'] . "' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
          <div class='panel-body'>
           " . $row['Answer'] . "
          </div>
    </div>
</div>


";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

((is_null($___mysqli_res = mysqli_close($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]))) ? false : $___mysqli_res); //Make sure to close out the database connection
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "student_data")



?>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Colapse</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
            $count = 0;
            $fetch = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student_cs");
            if (mysqli_num_rows($fetch) > 0) {
                while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch)) {
                    $count++;
            ?>

                    <div class="col-4">

                        <p>
                            <button  <?php $count; ?> class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                <h5> <?php echo $record['s_name']; ?> </h5>
                            </button>
                        </p>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                               <h3>  <?php echo $record['id']; ?> </h3> 
                               <h4>  <?php echo $record['s_name']; ?> </h4> 
                               <h5>  <?php echo $record['rollnumber']; ?> </h5> 
                               <h6>  <?php echo $record['class']; ?> </h6> 

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



            <?php  }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).